# Behavior of Firefox when self signed certifcate in the server is changed

Tags: firefox, webserver, self-signed, certificate-revocation

I have a webserver (running on a small embedded device) which issues self signed certificate. Firefox connects to the server and the page is loaded fine. We have a web client that continuously requests data from the server. When the server certificate is changed keeping the browser connection to the server intact, Firefox is unable to recognize the new certificate and it uses the older certificate to communicate with the server. This causes Firefox to reset the connection and the web client issues further request to the server and proceeding connections fail too. This causes the device to choke as the webserver is loaded with multiple requests. When I press the refresh button things fall in place and firefox fetches the new certificate. How do I enable exception handler in firefox or is there any options to detect the change in server certificate so that the browser can start using the new server certificate to communicate. With Chrome or IE I do not see the problem, IE prompts a prop up mentioning the certificate is changed.